# Overflow:Hidden not working on Transition Scale

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, css-transforms

I'm trying to have my thumbnails scale up but not have it go outside the 300px x 300px area.  I have read the questions on here and I still couldn't get mine to work.

This is what it looks like:
http://jsbin.com/nuduciyaja/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<body>
    <div class=flexContainer>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1032px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.images {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

}

.flexContainer img {
    border: 5px black solid;
}
```

and this is what I want it to look like:
http://jsbin.com/hunikaruxu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: If you have both the code then what is the problem...?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the same effect through Flex box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change some html structure and css as snippet below

```css
/*=======================================
  GALLERY SECTION ANIMATION
  =======================================*/

.flexContainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1032px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: DodgerBlue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px black solid;
}
/* ================================= 
  Photo Overlay Transitions
==================================== */

img {
    transition: transform .5s;
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
  <div class="photoContainer">
  <div class=flexContainer>
      <div class="images">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img  src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you!  Would you point me in the direction to learn why the layout had to be the way it is for it to work?